# Oledb 4.0 is not registered on the local machine (64 bit)

Tags: oledb, setup-deployment

I have created my setup in .net framework 2.0 and im using Windows 7 and its 64 Bit.Gives the error when i open the application Unhandled Exception:"Oledb 4.0  is not registered on the local machine"How to fix problem.(My works for 32 bit fine.. No problem)

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is that you're using Jet but there's no 64 bit version of Jet. The easiest way to fix this problem is to change your app to be compiled as 32 bit (in advanced compiler options I think).

Otherwise you might be able to do it by changing your code to use ACE instead (which is a continuation of Jet), but I'm not sure. You can find some details about Jet vs ACE in this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) article.

Comment: Correct. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/45aa44dd-0e6f-42e5-a9d6-9be5c5c8fcd1

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem occur all of a sudden and it wasn't a "Jet" problem as it previously worked, and then stopped working.  As it turned out, the application pool that the site was running under had "Enable 32-bit applications" changed to "False".  When I changed back to "True", the OleDb error went away.